# How to design set of flash cards in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I wonder what's the best way to create set of flashcards in InDesign, as I've never done it before.

Situation 1. The client is ok with a template they will fill on their own. So, I presume I can do the interactive pdf for them with back and front side design (each, separate page in Indesign, both in one pdf file). Correct me if I'm wrong please. Then the client create let's say 60 two-sided cards = 60 pdfs which they can merge, or just send to the printer and they will do the imposition there?

Situation 2. I get all the data I need to put on the flashcards. But then I'm not really sure how to put the texts into the correct frames on my design. I would probably experiment with autoflow, but I only did that for long chunks of text, not the flash cards contents. Do you have any idea of how to transfer data for flash cards into InDesign layout, so I don't have to deal with each one of them separately?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [Data Merge function](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/data-merge.html). Whatever they want on the flash cards can easily be imported using this from a .CSV file. You can also have it auto-populate additional pages as needed.